# Glassfish War deployment Jar not loaded

Tags: java, jar, glassfish, classpath, apache-axis

I have a very annoying problem.

So I want to include 2 jar files in my java web application (.war file) - to be loaded on glassfish version 2.1.

The files are:

`axis2-adb-1.4.1.jar` and `wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar`.

In my console application, I simply add these to my classpath and they run fine. However, when I deploy this to glassfish (jars are placed in `WEB-INF/lib/`) I get this:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault:
>   org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException:
>   Can not invoke the getTypeObject
>   method in the extension mapper class

I noticed that in my console application, when I removed `wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar` from my classpath, I would get this exact same error. So my feeling is that this jar is not loaded some how.

I then moved on to repackaging the jars together. I made this big axis2+wstx.jar and loaded it into my glassfish project. Same error... It is definately loading since without the axis2 jar it would throw a axis2 class not def exception way earlier.

So my theory is that glassfish is loading the jars lazily and since neither the axis2 jar nor my main program requires this wstx jar, it is not loaded correctly. But I am probably totally wrong.

I really hope someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with GF v2 b49, [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) is integrated as part of Glassfish along with [sjsxp](https://sjsxp.dev.java.net/) which remains the default parser. To enable Woodstox set the following system properties on the server side:

```
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
-Djavax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory
```

More details in [Woodstox in Glassfish v2](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhaktimehta/archive/2007/06/woodstox_in_gla_1.html).

If using the integrated Woodstox doesn't meet your requirements, then maybe try to activate the "class loading delegation feature" in the `sun-web.xml` file by setting by setting `delegate="false"` in the `class-loader` element. Something like that:

```
<sun-web-app>
  <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</sun-web-app>
```

Comment: holy crap this works. You're amazing. I'll look more into setting these system properties :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is the same class in both of jars. And somehow class without getTypeObject method is loaded as first. If there is chance to change the order of loaded jars in classpath it would help.